# Error when regressing on residuals of a previous regression. Why?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to regress twice

```
dat <- read.csv("data/prices.csv")
reg1a <- lm(dat$size~dat$rooms)
reg1b <- lm(dat$rent,reg1a$residuals)
```

Running `reg1a` is not a problem. Then I want to regress variable rent from `dat` on the residuals from the first regression `reg1a`. However I get this error message. What am I doing wrong?

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `~` in `reg1b`, so `lm()` thinks your formula is just `dat$rent`, which is not a valid formula. Changing it to

```r
reg1b <- lm(dat$rent~reg1a$residuals)
```

should remove the error.

Comment: Unrelated to error, but probably also worth pointing out that it is preferable to use the `data` argument e.g. `lm(size ~ rooms, data=dat)` ; saves a bit of pain going forward